# MongoDb get only one sub document along with the whole document

Tags: mongodb, laravel, document

So I have a product document which has a nested images document. 
The structure is like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551e617eccfff2fc193c9869"),
    "currency" : "US DOllar",
    "images" : [
        {
            "filename" : "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg",
            "height" : NumberLong(500),
            "width" : NumberLong(500),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-04-07T10:35:10.142Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2015-04-03T09:53:31.168Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("551e631bccfff278173c9869"),
            "deleted_at" : ISODate("2015-04-03T09:53:43.102Z")
        },
        {
            "filename" : "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_sameer.jpg",
            "height" : NumberLong(500),
            "width" : NumberLong(500),
            "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-04-03T10:00:39.969Z"),
            "created_at" : ISODate("2015-04-03T10:00:39.969Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("551e64c7ccfff200173c9869")
        }
    ],
    "is_active" : "1",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2015-04-07T08:05:15.932Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-04-03T09:46:38.340Z"),
}
```

Now I want only one sub document, i.e. image whose `filename` is "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg" along with the whole document.
How can I do that?
So i got the answer to do it in mongo .. now how can i do that in laravel with jessenger/mongo-db package..

Comment: possible duplicate of [return only 1 element of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445701/return-only-1-element-of-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding this you should use following query.

```
db.collectionName.find({"images.filename":"551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg"},{"images.$.filename":1,"currency":1}).pretty()
```

Comment: Just one more thing how can i get the product name as well.??

Comment: @SameerShaikh your document strcutre don't have product name field,check new edited answer  I added `currency`

Comment: Oh k your answer worked.. now do you know how to execute this with Laravel,I am using jessenger/mongo-db package

Comment: @SameerShaikh sorry but, I don't know more about `Laravel` I edited your question and taged to `Laravel` .

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`$elemMatch`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator

```
db.product.find(
    {"images.filename": "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg"}, 
    {
        "images": {
            "$elemMatch": {"filename": "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg"}
        },
        "currency": 1, "is_active": 1, "updated_at": 1, "created_at": 1 
     }
)
```

Alternatively you can also use the [**`$ projection`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator:

```
  db.product.find(
        {"images.filename": "551e617eccfff2fc193c9869_logo-big.jpg"}, 
        {
            "images.$": 1, "currency": 1, "is_active": 1, "updated_at": 1, "created_at": 1 
        }
    )
```